# Extracting domains from a CSV URL column using Miller

Tags: ubuntu, text-processing, csv, miller

Having CSV content similar to this:

```
Family,URL,IP,FirstSeen
Pony,http://officeman.tk/images/admin.php,207.180.230.128,01-06-2019
Pony,http://learn.cloudience.com/ojekwaeng/yugo/admin.php,192.145.234.108,01-06-2019
Pony,http://vman23.com/ba24/admin.php,95.213.204.53,01-06-2019
```

I'm aware that the `URL` column can be selected using:

```bsh
mlr --mmap --csv --skip-comments --headerless-csv-output cut -f 'URL'
```

How could domains be extracted using Miller w/out piping to other commands?

**Desired Output:**

```
officeman.tk
learn.cloudience.com
vman23.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Swiss Army knife of Miller is the [put](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-verbs.html#put) verb - which gives you access to an entire [domain specific language](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-dsl.html#dsl-reference) for transforming your data. From there there are several approaches:

- matching and capturing the domain portion of the URL with a regular expression
- trimming the leading and trailing components using regular expressions
- splitting the URL as a delimited string

So for example

```
mlr --mmap --csv --skip-comments --headerless-csv-output put -S '
  $URL =~ "https?://([^/]+)"; $Domain = "\1"
' then cut -f Domain file.csv
```

or

```
mlr --mmap --csv --skip-comments --headerless-csv-output put -S '
  m = splitnvx($URL,"/"); $Domain = m[3]
' then cut -f Domain file.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with usage of other commands you can try `awk`. And the command will be something like:

```
awk -F\/ 'FNR!=1 {print $3}' input_file.csv
```

The idea is to use `/` as delimiter and print field 3

Comment: For my purposes this works, thanks! The `FNR` trick is nice.

Answer (score 1):

running

```
mlr --c2n put '$m = splitnvx($URL,"/")[3]' then cut -f m input.csv
```

you will have

```
officeman.tk
learn.cloudience.com
vman23.com
```